# How do I use iFileDialog in a VC++ 2010 project converted from VC++ 6.0?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, com, visual-c++-2010

I am able to use a FileSaveDialog (Common Item Dialog) in a VC++ 2010 app like this:

```
IFileDialog *pFileDialog;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileSaveDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pFileDialog));
```

but when I put this code into my project that has been converted from VC++ 6.0 to VC++ 2010 I get the following error:

> "error C2787: 'IFileDialog' : no GUID has been associated with this object"

I also get a red squiggle under the `IID_PPV_ARGS` macro and the float-over error:

> "operand of _uuidof must have a class or enum type for which _declspec(uuid('...')) has been specified"

I am NOT using the Common Language Runtime Support (/clr) in either project.

How do I associate a GUID with my object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I had set a compiler flag targeting the Win XP OS.  That's why a feature introduced in Vista wasn't defined.

I had `_WIN32_WINNT = 0x0501` (WinXP).  When I changed it to `0x0600` (Vista) the IFileDialog was defined.

Mark, your suggestion about looking into the definition of IFileDialog lead me to the cause.  It led me to the `ShObjIdl.h` file but the section where IFileDialog was defined was greyed out, leading me up to the `#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_VISTA)` conditional.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My VC++ 6.0 doesn't define IFileDialog, not in the base package and not in the Windows SDK. Did you back port it from somewhere?

I would look at the definition of IFileDialog in VC++ 10. I'm guessing it's defined with the benefit of some macro, and that macro includes or excludes the `_declspec(uuid('...'))` depending on some compile-time constant which is set wrong.

**Edit:** In VC++ 10 IFileDialog is defined with the help of the MIDL_INTERFACE macro, in ShObjIdl.h. The MIDL_INTERFACE macro is defined in 3 different files, so it's hard to tell which definition you're picking up; they're all different. However I don't see any way in which the definition wouldn't be associated with a GUID.

Is it possible you're doing a forward definition of IFileDialog on your own that does not include the GUID?

Comment: I wasn't using IFileDialog in VC++ 6.0.  I'm adding it to the project after it has been converted to VC++ 2010.

Comment: IFileDialog is defined in ShObjIdl.h like this: 'code' #if defined(__cplusplus) && !defined(CINTERFACE)
    
    MIDL_INTERFACE("42f85136-db7e-439c-85f1-e4075d135fc8")
    IFileDialog : public IModalWindow
    {......  This looks like IFileDialog is associated with a GUID via the MIDL_INTERFACE macro.